# Error in <Trans /> component with react-i18next: Nothing returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

When I try to interpolate some React components with the `react-i18next` `Trans` component I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Trans(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I am calling the `Trans` component like so:

```
<Trans
     t={l as TFunction}
     defaults="hello <chip>{{cohortName}}</chip> <bold>{{jobName}}</bold>"
     values={{
                cohortName,
                jobName,
     }}
     components={{
                chip: (
                  <Chip>
                    <></>
                  </Chip>
                ),
                bold: <strong />,
     }}
 />
```

I cannot see why this is a problem as according to the [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0) this should be ok.

I do not think the issue is with `react-i18next` Trans component but am not sure. Any ideas?

I have tried an alternative version where I use a template as the return value from the `Trans` component:

```
               <Trans
                  t={t}
                  defaults="hello <1>{{cohortName}}</1> <2>{{jobName}}</2>"
                  values={{
                    cohortName,
                    jobName,
                  }}
                >
                  Hello <Chip>{{ cohortName }}</Chip>{" "}
                  <strong>{{ jobName }}</strong>
                </Trans>
```

This throws:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {cohortName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Which lead me to tray using an alternate prefix and suffix like so:

```
<Trans
     t={t}
     defaults="hello <1>%%cohortName%%</1> <2>%%jobName%%</2>"
     tOptions={{
                interpolation: {
                  prefix: "%%",
                  sufix: "%%",
                },
     }}
     values={{
                cohortName,
                jobName,
     }}
     >
     Hello <Chip>%%cohortName%%</Chip>{" "}
     <strong>%%jobName%%</strong>
 </Trans>
```

No errors thrown but the values `cohortName` & `jobName` are rendered as plain text and not the value from the component that `<Trans />` is a child of.

Comment: I believe the problem is in the trans component not here. It looks like <Trans/> didn't return anything in its render function.

Answer (score 0):

`Trans` component might be missing `i18n` instance it automatically obtains from `I18nContext` so you have to pass it to the component via `i18n` prop.

Updated code:

```
const { l, 18n } = useTranslation(...);

<Trans
     t={l as TFunction}
     i18n={i18n}
     defaults="hello <chip>{{cohortName}}</chip> <bold>{{jobName}}</bold>"
     values={{
                cohortName,
                jobName,
     }}
     components={{
                chip: (
                  <Chip>
                    <></>
                  </Chip>
                ),
                bold: <strong />,
     }}
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

Objects are not valid react children:

```
                  Hello <Chip>{{ cohortName }}</Chip>{" "}
                  <strong>{{ jobName }}</strong>
```

Remember { } inside JSX is an escape into javascript.
So `{{ cohortName }}` is just evaluating `{ cohortName }` which is shorthand for `{'cohortName': cohortName }` which is an object.

And objects are not valid react children. You probably just want to render the string cohortName here `{cohortName}`

As for the "Nothing returned from render" error we'd have to see the Trans components source code to help there.